# How does import table command in Hive fetches the schema?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hive, schema, avro

I have created a table in Avro schema.Here is create script.

```
CREATE TABLE `old_db.MyTable`(
  `fileld1` string COMMENT '', 
  `field2` string COMMENT '', 
  `field3` string COMMENT '')
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.avro.AvroSerDe' 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  '/data/gaurav/work/hive/old_db/MyTable'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'COLUMN_STATS_ACCURATE'='false', 
  'avro.schema.url'='/data/gaurav/work/hive/old_db/SCHEMA/MyTable.avsc')
```

I am exporting this table to a staging database staging_db.
use old_db;
export table myTable to '/data/gaurav/staging/hive/staging_db/MyTable'

If I go to to the path `/data/gaurav/staging/hive/staging_db/MyTable`
it contains two subdirectories
`data/gaurav/staging/hive/staging_db/MyTable/data` which contains the `.avro` files
and `data/gaurav/staging/hive/staging_db/MyTable/_metadata`.

After this I am importing this table to a different target database target_db

```
use target_db;
import table MyTable from '/data/gaurav/staging/hive/staging_db/MyTable'
```

after importing the table is created and is populated with data.While exporting and importing the schema location remains unchanged and while the table is created in target_db,its schema is still pointing to old location i.e `/data/gaurav/work/hive/old_db/SCHEMA/MyTable.avsc`.

From where the newly created MyTable is fetching the schema from if the .avsc file is not getting exported and imported?

Answer (score 0):

In this case you should allow the user to select the directory of location on the command prompt while running the script. 
It means when the script runs on dev server then while running the script, it should ask the user for the location where the table should be saved. The same is for stage environment.
Use '$' command to allow the user to input the location at runtime.

Comment: Noted bt my question is if .avsc file is not getting exported how the newly created table is able to read schema when it is only reading .avro and metadata?.Is it reading from metadata?